# LEFT returns different results for the same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can some one explain me why the results of LEFT are different? For:

```
Declare @f as float
set @f = 40456510.

select LEFT(cast(@f as float), LEN(4045.)), LEFT(404565., LEN(4045.))
```

I got:

```
     |
------------ 
4.04 | 4045
```

Is there a default cast which causes this? [Fiddle SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/185b8/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `LEFT(...)` on the `FLOAT` value you are converting it to a string representation of the number as it's a string function. If you convert the value to a `varchar` for example, you'll see what the output is:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@f as float) AS VARCHAR(100))
```

You get: `'4.04565e+007'`

So the first 4 characters of that are: `'4.04'`

Comment: Do you now why? If not, do you know how to get first N numbers of

Comment: @orim are you only interested in whole numbers or do you want decimal places if they are present? it's not clear from your input and `LEN(4045.)` what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have INTs stored in the FLOAT's column (not my design and I can't change it). I created an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f1d86/5

Comment: @orim just cast to `int` instead then: `select LEFT(cast(@f as int)`

Answer (score 0):

The first one is taking the left 4 characters of the exponential representation. Why I don't know.

You are applying a string function [Left()] to a float variable.